# Stream of hashmap entry pairs in Java8?

Tags: java, hashmap, java-8, java-stream

In `Java8`, having a `HashMap<Integer, City> capitals` I want to get a stream of capital pairs `Stream<Map.Entry<Integer, City>, Map.Entry<Integer, City>> capitalPairs` filtered by the `Integer`. How can I do that?

Example: `capitals = { (1, Amsterdam), (2, Barcelona), (3, Dortmund) }` then (filtering is defined as `first integer < second integer`):

```
capitalPairs = [
( (1, Amsterdam), (2, Barcelona) ),
( (1, Amsterdam), (3, Dortmund) ),
( (2, Barcelona), (3, Dortmund) ) ]
```

Comment: What do you mean by pairs? Do you mean all combinations, or all permutations? Are you sure you need such a complex costruct as I suspect you just need all key pairs.

Comment: If you had a `TreeMap` instead of a `HashMap`, @PeterLawrey's solution could be improved by using `tailMap(k1)` for the inner stream.

Answer (score 3):

Say you want all key apirs where `first < second` to avoid duplicate combinations.

```
capitals.keySet().stream().flatMap(k1 ->
    capitals.keySet().stream().filter(k2 -> k1 < k2).map(k2 -> Pair.of(k1, k2)))
    // do something with the pair of keys, lookup the city as required.
```

You can do this with entrySet() instead of keySet() but this is more cumbersome.

```
capitals.entrySet().stream().flatMap(e1 ->
    capitals.entrySet().stream().filter(e2 -> e1.getValue() < e2.getValue()).map(e2 -> Pair.of(e1, e2)))
    // do something with the Pair of entry(s)
```

Comment: @BrandonMcHomery you need to have an implementation of `Pair.of(a, b)`  I would just use the Stream as is, rather than assign it to a variable.